# how to remove all similar words inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove all same words from array javascript

```
var e = ["1A","2A","3A","4A"];
```

how to remove the all `A` from the variable e so that i can get like

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

Comment: e.map(v => v.substr(0,1))

Comment: Will it always be an `A` at the end? Or do you want to keep numbers at the start regardless of the letter(s) at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way will work all browsers

```
var word = 'killMe'; // word that you whant to remove 
var bad_array = ['1killMe','2 killMe','killMe 3']; // from where you whant to remove it

for (var i=0; i<bad_array.length; i++){
  bad_array[i] = bad_array[i].split(word).join('');
}

console.dir(bad_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map()`, you can call `replace()` on each element of the array:

```js
var e = ["1A","2A","3A","4A"];
e = e.map(function(elt) {
  return elt.replace('A', "");
});
console.log(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` over an array to apply a function on every element of it.

```
console.log(
    e.map( 
        function(element){
             return element.replace("A", "") //Remove "A"
        }
    )
)
```

You can change the function to do whatever you like.

**Note:** `map` does not change the original array, it just returns a new one. That means that you have to assign the returned value back to `e` if you want to change `e`.

Newer browsers support [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which are a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to write [lambdas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).

Here is the code using these new arrow functions

```
console.log(
    e.map( 
        element => element.replace("A", "") //Remove "A"
    )
)
```

or as one line (with the argument being `el` instead of `element` to shorten it)

`console.log(e.map(el => el.replace("A", "")))`

Or, to assign the new value back to `e` you can do

`e = e.map(el => el.replace("A", ""))`

**Remember:** IE does not support arrow functions (but it is being replaced by Microsoft Edge so that should not be a problem). If you want to make sure every single browser is definitely compatible, use the longer form of `function(arg){return ...;}` instead of the more readable `(arg) => ...`. However, arrow functions should work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var f = e.join();

var g = f.replace(/A/g, '');

g.split(',');
```